# DJANGO POST GET not working after i18n translation

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have multiple POST requests from my template for example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/apply_payment',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            basket: JSON.stringify(basket),
            key: $('#key_input').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_TOKEN
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#key_input").val("");
        },
        ...
```

I read in the `basket` data in a view.py like this:

```
basket = request.POST.get('basket', '')
```

In the urls.py I have these urls in the form of:

```
path('apply_payment', entrance_api.apply_payment, name='apply_payment'),
```

Now lately I added `i18n_patterns` into the URLs, and translated all of my pages, however the AJAX calls stopped working. I guess it is becase the URLs are dynamically changing between selected languages, but I might be wrong.

For example the shows `basket` variable is always `None` in the view now. How can I fix this?

Comment: try making /apply_payment into a variable like this {% url '..:..' as apply_payment_url %} before the ajax call and replace it in $.ajax like this: url: {{ apply_payment_url }}

Comment: @alex That was my idea as well, but the problem is that the calls are in a JS file where I cannot load the DJANGO tags

Comment: Why not move them in the html file?

Comment: @alex Because I have around 10k lines of JS script. AFAIK its bad practice to keep it in the HTML file, also it will be extremely clustered and cluttered

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I had to prepend a language code to the POST request URL:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/en/apply_payment', // prepend a language code or even better: use window.location.href
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            basket: JSON.stringify(basket),
            key: $('#key_input').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_TOKEN
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#key_input").val("");
        },
```